# merge/append json with different key

Tags: php, json

what i want

i want a array look like something this

```
  array
  (
  [0]=>country
  (
    [id] => 
    [name] => 
    [url] => 
      )
 [city] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 68870
                [name] => Abu Dhabi
                [url] => abudhabi-ae
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 68872
                [name] => Das Island
                [url] => dasisland-ae
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 68873
                [name] => Dubai
                [url] => dubai-ae
            )
       [1]=>country
         (
        [id] => 
        [name] => 
       [url] => 
      )

      [city] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 68870
                [name] => Abu Dhabi
                [url] => abudhabi-ae
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 68872
                [name] => Das Island
                [url] => dasisland-ae
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 68873
                [name] => Dubai
                [url] => dubai-ae
            )
         )
```

i have written code like this

```
   <?php
      require('/home/indiamart/public_html/serve-biztradeshows-com/db.php');
     $query="select distinct ct.name name , listing_combo.country country from country ct join listing_combo on ct.id=listing_combo.country ";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
   {
        $country_id= $row['country'];

       $arr = array();
       $arr[]=$row;
       $arr1['country']=json_encode($arr);
       $select_city="select id,name,url from city where country like'$country_id' ";
        $city=mysql_query($select_city);

       while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($city))
       {
        $arr[]=$row1;
        }
         $arr1['city']=json_encode($arr);
       }
       print_r($arr1);
       echo "</br>";
       ?>
```

but it print only the last result of query 
and ites format is like this

array also can be created so i can encode it at last but its format should be fine.

array(

[country]=>

[city]=>

)

please help

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is becaues you are always reinitialize your `$arr = array();` in the loop. Put this line outside of your `while` loop.

Also please do not use mysql functions because they are deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO instead.

And avoid sql injection, escape the variables in your query.

I can not test this, but you need something like this:

```
require('/home/indiamart/public_html/serve-biztradeshows-com/db.php');
//In your db.php create a $conn variable, what is a connection (resource) to 
//your database with mysqli_connect function.
//See mysqli in php manual.

$countryQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT ct.name name , listing_combo.country country "
        . "FROM country ct "
        . "JOIN listing_combo ON ct.id=listing_combo.country";
//Use mysqli instead of mysql functions since they are deprecated.
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $countryQuery);
$countries = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //Do not need to create a new variable, what you do not use anywhere else.
    //$country_id= $row['country']; You can use $row['country'] 
    //in your query cityQuery later.

    //$arr1['country']=json_encode($arr);
    //Json do not need here, since, you want an array, not a string.
    $countries[$i]['country'] = $row;

    //Avoid sql injection, so use mysqli_real_escape_string
    $cityQuery = "SELECT id,name,url "
            . "FROM city "
            . "WHERE country like'" . mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $row['country']) . "'";
    $cityResult = mysqli_query($conn, $cityQuery);
    $j = 0;
    while ($cityRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($cityResult)) {
        //Add all cities to the current country
        $countries[$i]['country']['city'][$j] = $cityRow;
        //Incrase the key of the array cities
        $j++;
    }
    //Incrase the key of countries
    $i++;
}
print_r($countries);
```

I made some modification in your code. Renamed all the variables, to tell, what they include.

I am using mysqli functions instead of mysql functions.

Removed unused variables.

Added comments, so you can see what  i am doing.

Comment: worked but format is not right its printing detail of all country, first then detail of all city

Comment: i have updated my question plz have a look on that [lolka_bolka](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1087195/lolka-bolka)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot connect to your DB so I cannot test. But the feeling should be that:

```
     <?php
    require('/home/indiamart/public_html/serve-biztradeshows-com/db.php');
    $query="select distinct ct.name name , listing_combo.country country from country ct join listing_combo on ct.id=listing_combo.country ";
    $result=mysql_query($query);

    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $countries[$row['country']]=$row;
    }

    foreach ($countries as $country_id => $country_row) {
        $select_city="select id,name,url from city where country like'$country_id' ";
        $city=mysql_query($select_city);
        while($row1=mysql_fetch_assoc($city))
        {
            $cities[]=$row1;
        }
        foreach ($cities as $city_id => $city_row) {
            $countries[$country_id][$city_id]=$city_row;
        }
    }

    print_r($countries);
    echo "</br>";
?>
```

You had better to query countries first to avoid data reset. Thanks for the good commenter.

Comment: he is using result and row for countries and city (as resource) and row1 for the cities, so i think, there are no conflict there.

Comment: i am unable to get it  and its  hanging my computer and format is not right

Comment: i have updated my question plz have a look on that [Sinri Edogawa](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3066271/sinri-edogawa)

Comment: Your new format seems to have duplicated index 'city', are you sure the countries and cities are of the same level?